# vb.net / events?

Tags: vb.net, events

I have a DataGridView and sometimes I use the CellValueChanged Event but othertime I don't want it to trigger. Is there a way that I can remove an event sub and then restore it.

I have 5 columns with a ComboBox. After licking one, and then another, the line bellow keeps repeating until stack crashes

```
 Private Sub dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) _
                Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
        Try
            Debug.Print("entered the EditingControlShowing")
            Dim ColName As String = Me.DataGridView1.Columns(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).Name
            If ColName = "Col1" Or ColName = "Col2" Or ColName = "Col3" Or ColName = "Col4" Or ColName = "Col5" Then

                'the column you want to cast
                Dim cmb As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
                RemoveHandler cmb.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf cmb_SelectedIndexChanged
                AddHandler cmb.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf cmb_SelectedIndexChanged
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Sub cmb_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Try
            Debug.Print("about to update cell") <<===== this line just repeats until stack crashes
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).Value = CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem
            UpdateAvgColumn(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Sub UpdateAvgColumn(ByVal r As Integer)
        Dim avg As Single = 0.0
        Debug.Print("UpdateAvgColumn")
        If CInt(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Col1").Value) <> 0 And CInt(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Col2").Value) <> 0 And _
            CInt(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Col3").Value) <> 0 And CInt(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Col4").Value) <> 0 And _
            CInt(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Col5").Value) <> 0 Then
            avg = CSng((CInt(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Col1").Value) + CInt(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Col2").Value) + _
                        CInt(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Col3").Value) + CInt(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Col4").Value) + _
                            CInt(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("Col5").Value)) / 5)
        End If
        Me.DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells("AvgCol").Value = avg
    End Sub
```

Comment: What are the conditions under which you *don't* want it to fire? Can you catch these in the event sub and suppress the normal action under these conditions?

Comment: As sasfrog said, we need more details.  When you say "sometimes" you need to be able to explicitly say when to TRIGGER and when NOT to Trigger.  Once you can answer that, you've likely answered your original question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can remove event handlers, by using RemoveHandler method. But the better approach will be validate the condition in the event and do process or ignore.

Comment: My situation is that I have a DataGridView and one of it's columns is a CombBox. The user can select the entry from the CombBox or enter it by hand. When Selecting from the ComboBox it triggers before the underlying DataGridView Cell is updated, so I update it with current cell = the value selected. But when I do this it seems to trigger events and end up in some loop. So I want to disconnect the even until after I do this line. But I think what you are suggesting is superior thought I'm not sure how I can do it here.

Comment: @bochur1 Can you use a different event? I can't remember their names but maybe you want afterUpdate or something, depending on what you're trying to do in the event.

Comment: What I'm finding is when I do the cell = value it repeats this line for ever until the stack crashes. Is there away to post code here to show you what I'm referring to?

Comment: You could edit your question and use the code tags to show what you're doing. That will definitely contribute to getting an answer to your question.

Comment: I removed it. Apparently this was not what was causing the problem.

Comment: Now what the problem you are facing?

Comment: After I click on combobox and then another it goes into an endless loop (?) until the stack crashes. I point out in the code which line it keeps on repeating in this loop 

Debug.Print("about to update cell") <<===== this line just repeats until stack crashes
           Me.DataGridView1.Rows(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).Value = CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem